# Where are words stored when using the "Add word to dictionary" feature within a text editor?

Tags: dictionary, spell-checking, hunspell

I would like to create a backup of my personal dictionary.

Where are words stored that I added via "Add word to dictionary"?

Below example shows [Ghostwriter](https://github.com/wereturtle/ghostwriter).

[image]

Comment: Which program are you using?  Is it LibreOffice?

Comment: @L.D.James in this particular case it was [Ghostwriter](https://github.com/wereturtle/ghostwriter).

Comment: Your question is too broad. There are many programs which have "Add word to dictionary" feature

Comment: @Anwar He originally thought that all programs used a common personal dictionary area.  So he wanted to backup his added words for all programs.  The answer clarified your point that he would backup the personal dictionary in question, then backup any other personal dictionaries by their specific area.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would depend on the text editor or the application itself.

**For ghostwriter the configuration area is:**

```
~/.config/ghostwriter/dictionaries/personal
```

**for `Libreoffice` the configuration area is:**

```
~/.config/libreoffice/[version #]/user/workbook
```

Replace `[version #]` with the version you are running.  Ubuntu 16.04 ships with version 4.  So the area would be:

```
~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/workbook
```

Comment: Thank you! Each application thus uses its own location to store custom words, correct?

Comment: @orschiro Yes.  I added an FYI to the answer on that matter.

Comment: That's great, thanks! I am wondering why they have never centralised all custom dictionaries.

Comment: @orschiro If you wrote an application that uses a particular jargon you would most likely have an area so store your specific words and might not want to have them conflict with other dictionaries.  So you'd most likely have (as all programs such as Firefox, Chrome, and so on) and area for customization of your program's environment.  If you look at the many programs of the `~/.config` area it'll probably make more sense.

Comment: @orschiro: if the syntaxes seem to match between the files, you could always use symlinks to keep a centralised custom dict.

Comment: @progo good idea to create symlinks. I might try this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Spend a little time to find it for TextStudio

in addition to the above hint:

```
~/.conf/textstudio/texstudio[locale].ign
```

where [locale] is the used locale like en_US. Note that it has the ign extension, like ignored words. Not sure yet how texstudio is differentiating  ignored from added words.

The standard dictionaries are all located at one point, in my case

```
/usr/share/hunspell
```

could be an idea to use symlinks and put the user dictionaries in a shared folder. Most of the time the words not present in dictionaries are context related, company business ecc